# ¿Como obtener los Links que contiene un text-area con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quiero obtener una lista de descripción de los Links que pueda contener mi TextArea, como puedo realizar esto ya que necesito solo enviar la lista de los links.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes usar una expresión regular para obtener el resultado esperado:

```js
    function findMatches(regex, str, matches = []) {
       const res = regex.exec(str)
       res && matches.push(res[0]) && findMatches(regex, str, matches)
    
       return matches
    }
    
    var textArea = "hpoasodi as http://veflat.com asdoijqw iodj https://hostingdatos.com a sdasd ";
    var matches = findMatches(/(?:ht|f)tps?:\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/[^"<]*)?/g, textArea)
    console.log(matches);
```

Solo tendrías que obtener en la variable textArea el valor de tu textArea.

algo cómo:

```
var textArea = document.getElementbyId("myTextAreaID").value;
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
Array [ "http://veflat.com", "https://hostingdatos.com" ]
```